# Player jumps only once using player.jump in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my player jump (from this tutorial https://opensource.com/article/19/12/jumping-python-platformer-game) but it only jumps once when you press `key_up` or key `"w"`. And when I look at the output produced in the terminal while I am running the `game.py` file I see that it was printed `jump` several times in the terminal.

**game.py:**

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

'''
Objects
'''

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # x location, y location, img width, img height, img file    
    def __init__(self,xloc,yloc,imgw,imgh,img):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',img)).convert()
        self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = yloc
        self.rect.x = xloc

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn a player
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.health = 10
        # gravity variables here
        self.collide_delta = 0
        self.jump_delta = 6
        self.score = 1
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1,9):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','spr' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
            self.images.append(img)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
    def jump(self,platform_list):
        self.jump_delta = 0
    def gravity(self):
        self.movey += 3.2  # how fast player falls

        if self.movey >= 15:
            self.movey = 6

        if self.rect.bottom > worldy and self.movey >= 0: # <-- uses bottom
           self.movey = 0
           self.rect.bottom = worldy # <-- uses bottom
    def control(self,x,y):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''
        plat_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, plat_list, False)
        for p in plat_hit_list:
            self.collide_delta = 0 # stop jumping
            self.movey = 0

            if self.rect.y > p.rect.y:
                self.rect.y = p.rect.y+ty
            else:
                self.rect.y = p.rect.y-ty
        if self.collide_delta < 6 and self.jump_delta < 6:
            self.jump_delta = 6*2
            self.movey -= 33  # how high to jump
            self.collide_delta += 6
            self.jump_delta    += 6

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > ani*3:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame//ani]

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > ani*3:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[(self.frame//ani)+4]

        # collisions
        enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy_list, False)
        for enemy in enemy_hit_list:
            self.health -= 1
            print(self.health)

        plat_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, plat_list, False)
        for p in plat_hit_list:
            self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top

        ground_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, ground_list, False)
        for g in ground_hit_list:
            self.movey = 0
            self.rect.y = worldy-ty-ty
            self.collide_delta = 0 # stop jumping
            if self.rect.y > g.rect.y:
               self.health -= 1
               print(self.health)


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn an enemy
    '''
    def __init__(self,x,y,img):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',img))
        #self.image.convert_alpha()
        #self.image.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.counter = 0

    def move(self):
        '''
        enemy movement
        '''
        distance = 80
        speed = 8

        if self.counter >= 0 and self.counter <= distance:
            self.rect.x += speed
        elif self.counter >= distance and self.counter <= distance*2:
            self.rect.x -= speed
        else:
            self.counter = 0

        self.counter += 1

class Level():
    def bad(lvl,eloc):
        if lvl == 1:
            enemy = Enemy(eloc[0],eloc[1],'yeti.png') # spawn enemy
            enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group() # create enemy group
            enemy_list.add(enemy)              # add enemy to group

        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )

        return enemy_list

    def loot(lvl,lloc):
        print(lvl)

    def ground(lvl,gloc,tx,ty):
        ground_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        i=0
        if lvl == 1:
            while i < len(gloc):
                ground = Platform(gloc[i],worldy-ty,tx,ty,'ground.png')
                ground_list.add(ground)
                i=i+1

        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )

        return ground_list

    def platform(lvl,tx,ty):
        plat_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        ploc = []
        i=0
        if lvl == 1:
            ploc.append((0,worldy-ty-128,3))
            ploc.append((300,worldy-ty-256,3))
            ploc.append((500,worldy-ty-128,4))

            while i < len(ploc):
                j=0
                while j <= ploc[i][2]:
                    plat = Platform((ploc[i][0]+(j*tx)),ploc[i][1],tx,ty,'ground.png')
                    plat_list.add(plat)
                    j=j+1
                print('run' + str(i) + str(ploc[i]))
                i=i+1

        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )

        return plat_list

'''
Setup
'''
worldx = 960
worldy = 720

fps = 40 # frame rate
ani = 4  # animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
main = True

BLUE  = (25,25,200)
BLACK = (23,23,23 )
WHITE = (254,254,254)
ALPHA = (0,255,0)

world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx,worldy])
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','stage.png')).convert()
backdropbox = world.get_rect()
player = Player() # spawn player
player.rect.x = 0
player.rect.y = 0
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10 # how fast to move

eloc = []
eloc = [200,20]
gloc = []
#gloc = [0,630,64,630,128,630,192,630,256,630,320,630,384,630]
tx = 64 #tile size
ty = 64 #tile size

i=0
while i <= (worldx/tx)+tx:
    gloc.append(i*tx)
    i=i+1

enemy_list = Level.bad( 1, eloc )
ground_list = Level.ground( 1,gloc,tx,ty )
plat_list = Level.platform( 1,tx,ty )

'''
Main loop
'''
while main == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                print("LEFT")
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                print("RIGHT")
                player.control(steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('jump')

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                player.jump(plat_list)

            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
    player.gravity() # check gravity
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)
    enemy_list.draw(world)
    ground_list.draw(world)
    plat_list.draw(world)
    for e in enemy_list:
        e.move()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

The original images are from here https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/opp2_sprites.zip but I have separated in imgur for easy explanation:

content folder **images**:

For enemy (sprit) is **yeti.png:** [image]

For background is **stage.png:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmyok.jpg

and the image of the player: **spr.png:** [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a jump, `self.collide_delta` and `self.jump_delta` have to be less than 6. See your code:

> ```py
> if self.collide_delta < 6 and self.jump_delta < 6:
>    self.jump_delta = 6*2
> ```

The issue is that `self.collide_delta` is not set 0, when the player hits a platform:
(in the 2nd case)

```
plat_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, plat_list, False)
for p in plat_hit_list:
    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
    self.collide_delta = 0 # <----- this is missing
```

Comment: ThankXD! I had seen these other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777962/how-to-make-your-sprite-jump-in-pygame and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062747/why-wont-my-character-jump-in-pygame-python and I tried to investigate the part `if self.rect.y > g.rect.y: self.health -=1  print(self.health)` I didn't realize anything was missing in the code.